# Node Apps on Ubuntu using pm2: Is my planned configuration correct?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, environment-variables, pm2

im currently planning to run node.js applications on my ubuntu virtual-server.

I'll show you my planned workflow to install, and you may say if there could be any problems or improvements.

Okay, here we go:

```
# Install Node.js as root

# Install the pm2 package:
$ sudo npm install -g pm2

# Add a user which will run all the node apps
$ sudo useradd node-user
$ sudo passwd node-user
$ sudo mkhomedir_helper node-user
$ sudo chsh -s /bin/bash node-user

# Create a dir where all node apps are located
$ sudo mkdir /var/node-apps
$ sudo chown node-user:node-user /var/node-apps
$ sudo ln -s /var/node-apps /home/node-user/node-apps

# Install auto-start script
$ sudo pm2 startup ubuntu

# From now on, don't use root! Execute the following as "node-user"

$ cd ~/node-apps
$ git clone https://github.com/bahuma/shop.git
$ cd shop
$ npm install
$ bower install

# Start an app with environment variables
$ IP=127.0.0.1 PORT=55443 DATABASE=[dburl] SESSION_SECRET=[secret] pm2 start server.js --name bahuma-shop

# Connect the pm2 to Keymetrics.io
$ pm2 link [KEY] [SECRET] bahuma-server
```

So this is my planned workflow. Would this work? Are there any problems?

Thank you in advance
Max